# Ethernet port/device not picked up at all in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

on my Windows 7 machine my ethernet port is not recognised at all. Even in device manager (shown below) it is nowhere and same as in network connections. I've tried installing the motherboard supported drivers for LAN but to no avail - returning an error message saying no network adapters found.

[image: Device manager]

[image: Network connections]

Thanks

Comment: Is this a new problem, i.e. the port used to exist?  Or is this a new install or new PC?  (1) Check the BIOS settings to make sure that the LAN port is enabled. (2) Get and boot a Linux "Live" CD, and see if Linux can detect the interface.

Comment: I've only ever used WiFi on this machine for a few years. Ethernet does work on Linux and I'll look into the BIOS now!

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in a known working PCI NIC and see what's going to happen, if it responds...your card has failed, but if both cards don't, there's definitely something wrong with your BIOS settings. Check if ethernet network cards are enabled and set correctly.